# Apple Mach-O Linker Error - Undefined symbols for architecture x86_64

Tags: ios, swift, xcode

Previously I'm using Xcode 9.2 and I can only build to simulator. Build to device will result to apple match O linker error.

Now that I updated Xcode to 9.4.1, I cannot build to simulator / device anymore. I got apple match O linker error like bellow:

```
Undefined symbols for architecture arm64:
  "type metadata for Foundation.NSFastEnumerationIterator", referenced from:
      type metadata accessor for Swift.EnumeratedIterator<Foundation.NSFastEnumerationIterator> in TableForm.o
  "Swift.FloatingPointSign.rawValue.getter : Swift.Int", referenced from:
      MyApp.TableForm.heightForView(Swift.String, font: __ObjC.UIFont, width: CoreGraphics.CGFloat) -> CoreGraphics.CGFloat in TableForm.o
      MyApp.MultilineCell.textViewDidChange(__ObjC.UITextView) -> () in MultilineCell.o
  "(extension in Swift):Swift.Collection< where A.Element: Swift.Equatable>.split(separator: A.Element, maxSplits: Swift.Int, omittingEmptySubsequences: Swift.Bool) -> [A.SubSequence]", referenced from:
      MyApp.TableForm.tableView(__ObjC.UITableView, cellForRowAt: Foundation.IndexPath) -> __ObjC.UITableViewCell in TableForm.o
.....
.....
```

(Got very much of them, more than 200 errors detected)
And it's all related to Swift's standard library / functionality / type.
e.g:

> "Swift.Array.remove(at: Swift.Int) -> A",
>
> "Swift.FloatingPointSign.rawValue.getter : Swift.Int",
>
> "generic specialization  of Swift.Array.removeAll(keepingCapacity: Swift.Bool) -> ()",
>
> "Swift.min(A, A, A, A...) -> A",
>
> "static Swift.String.+ infix(Swift.String, Swift.String) -> Swift.String"`

What I've tried so far:

- Delete derived data content.
- Update Pods.
- Check Build Phases -> Compiled
  Sources for every file needed (swift and objc classes / object that needed).

None of it helps with the issue. Wondering if there's anyone can help me with this?

EDIT:
Not sure if this is related or not but I also got these warnings:

```
ld: warning: Auto-Linking missing required architecture arm64 in file build/MyApp.app/Frameworks/libswiftCoreAudio.dylib (2 slices) 
ld: warning: Auto-Linking missing required architecture arm64 in file build/MyApp.app/Frameworks/libswiftCoreMedia.dylib (2 slices) 
ld: warning: Auto-Linking missing required architecture arm64 in file build/MyApp.app/Frameworks/libswiftAVFoundation.dylib (2 slices) 
ld: warning: Auto-Linking missing required architecture arm64 in file build/MyApp.app/Frameworks/libswiftSwiftOnoneSupport.dylib (2 slices) 
ld: warning: Auto-Linking missing required architecture arm64 in file build/MyApp.app/Frameworks/libswiftCore.dylib (2 slices) 
ld: warning: Auto-Linking missing required architecture arm64 in file build/MyApp.app/Frameworks/libswiftQuartzCore.dylib (2 slices) 
ld: warning: Auto-Linking missing required architecture arm64 in file build/MyApp.app/Frameworks/libswiftCoreImage.dylib (2 slices) 
ld: warning: Auto-Linking missing required architecture arm64 in file build/MyApp.app/Frameworks/libswiftCoreGraphics.dylib (2 slices)
ld: warning: Auto-Linking missing required architecture arm64 in file build/MyApp.app/Frameworks/libswiftMetal.dylib (2 slices)
ld: warning: Auto-Linking missing required architecture arm64 in file build/MyApp.app/Frameworks/libswiftsimd.dylib (2 slices)
ld: warning: Auto-Linking missing required architecture arm64 in file build/MyApp.app/Frameworks/libswiftFoundation.dylib (2 slices)
ld: warning: Auto-Linking missing required architecture arm64 in file build/MyApp.app/Frameworks/libswiftDispatch.dylib (2 slices)
ld: warning: Auto-Linking missing required architecture arm64 in file build/MyApp.app/Frameworks/libswiftObjectiveC.dylib (2 slices)
ld: warning: Auto-Linking missing required architecture arm64 in file build/MyApp.app/Frameworks/libswiftCoreFoundation.dylib (2 slices)
ld: warning: Auto-Linking missing required architecture arm64 in file build/MyApp.app/Frameworks/libswiftCoreData.dylib (2 slices)
ld: warning: Auto-Linking missing required architecture arm64 in file build/MyApp.app/Frameworks/libswiftUIKit.dylib (2 slices)
ld: warning: Auto-Linking missing required architecture arm64 in file build/MyApp.app/Frameworks/libswiftDarwin.dylib (2 slices)
```

Comment: Check what is the current Swift version you have used.

Comment: I used swift 4.0 in Xcode 9.2,
But the current XCode 9.4.1 only have Swift 4.1 option.

Comment: I think this will be the main issue. Check out the what's new in Swift 4.1: https://www.raywenderlich.com/97-what-s-new-in-swift-4-1

Comment: It's stated there `Swift 4.1 is source-compatible with Swift 4, so the new features won’t break your code if you’ve already migrated your project to Swift 4 using the Swift Migrator in Xcode` and also I haven't made any code change since updating the XCode. So I don't think I will have problem with code that running on simulator on previous XCode version.

Comment: Can you check out in `your target->Build Phase`? whether  `MultilineCell.m` and `TableForm.m` files exist there or not?

Comment: Yes, as I mentioned in the question, I've checked Target -> Build Phases -> Compiled Sources,
MultilineCell.swift and TableForm.swift (and also more swift and objc classes, object) are there.